# Vanilla JS selectors help for adding values from a set of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a button to run a function that will add the values of a group radio buttons, however I think I am coming undone on HOW to write the selectors. This is what I have and it at least does 'something' even if that something is 'undefined'

I need to do this in pure JavaScript as such (I have no idea how to deal with libraries or jQuery yet)

I've probably posted extraneous code in the snippet but I have tried to include what I think is relevant (the CSS is probably way too much to be honest)

I could do with a few pointers, I've been staring at this now for so long that I am not sure what I am reading anymore.

I think I will also need to parse the string to a number to fully complete this but I am struggling on the grab of this info (I'm self teaching so I'm sure I may have misread something somewhere)

I've been reading through other answers which is how I figured how I need to structure the function but not how to ask it.

Like I know how to bake the cake but I don't understand eggs!

Help a dumbass find her eggs!

```js
(function() {
  function testAttributes() {
    document.getElementById('testAttributesOutput').innerHTML = 'check' + physicalattribute;
    //get the value of the selected radio in group strength
    var str = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="strength"]:checked').value;
    //get the value of the selected radio in group dexterity
    var dex = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="dexterity"]:checked').value;
    //get the value of the selected radio in group stamina
    var sta = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="stamina"]:checked').value;
    //add the 3 values together
    var physicalattribute = str + dex + sta;
    //return value as a number not a string
    console.log(physicalattribute);
    //it prints a string where it expects a number - console prints NaN
  }
  // Validate attributes setup should display a a number between 0 and 12
  document.getElementById('testAttributes').onclick = testAttributes;
})();
```

```css
 

  html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

h1, h2, h3, p {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li input {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

li select {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

select {
    display: inline-block;
}

.attributes-wrapper, .abilities-wrapper, .description {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.advantages-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.statsBox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.attributeName {
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.attributeValue {
    align-content: right;
}

.attributes, .abilities, .description ul {
    width: 31%;
    margin: 0;
}

.advantages {
    width: 22%;
    margin: 0;
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}

.inline select {
    width: 147%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button id="testAttributes">Test Attributes</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      Are Attributes valid?:
      <span id="testAttributesOutput"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>ATTRIBUTES</h2>
    <div class="attributes-wrapper">
      <div class="attributes">
        <!-- Physical -->
        <h3>PHYSICAL</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="statsBox container">
              <div>
                <label for="strengthSpecialisation">Strength:</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="strengthSpecialisation" id="strengthSpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="statsBox">
              <div>
                <label for="dexteritySpecialisation">Dexterity:</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="dexteritySpecialisation" id="dexteritySpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="statsBox">
              <div class="attributeName" id="attributeName">
                <label for="staminaSpecialisation">Stamina:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="attributeValue" id="attributeValue">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="staminaSpecialisation" id="staminaSpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, there are just a couple things:

- You want to select a single element, so use `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll`. A `NodeList` doesn't have a `value` property, so accessing its `value` returns `undefined`.
- `.value`s always return strings - you need to convert them to numbers *before* you add them together.
- Only use `innerHTML` when you're deliberately using or inserting HTML markup (which can have security and encoding problems). When you're setting or retrieving text values, use `textContent` instead.

```js
(function() {
  function testAttributes() {
    //get the value of the selected radio in group strength
    var str = document.querySelector('input[name="strength"]:checked').value;
    //get the value of the selected radio in group dexterity
    var dex = document.querySelector('input[name="dexterity"]:checked').value;
    //get the value of the selected radio in group stamina
    var sta = document.querySelector('input[name="stamina"]:checked').value;
    //add the 3 values together
    var physicalattribute = Number(str) + Number(dex) + Number(sta);
    //return value as a number not a string
    console.log(physicalattribute);
    //it prints a string where it expects a number - console prints NaN
    document.getElementById('testAttributesOutput').textContent = 'check ' + physicalattribute;
  }
  // Validate attributes setup should display a a number between 0 and 12
  document.getElementById('testAttributes').onclick = testAttributes;
})();
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li input {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

li select {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

select {
  display: inline-block;
}

.attributes-wrapper,
.abilities-wrapper,
.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.advantages-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.statsBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.attributeName {
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.attributeValue {
  align-content: right;
}

.attributes,
.abilities,
.description ul {
  width: 31%;
  margin: 0;
}

.advantages {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inline select {
  width: 147%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button id="testAttributes">Test Attributes</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      Are Attributes valid?:
      <span id="testAttributesOutput"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>ATTRIBUTES</h2>
    <div class="attributes-wrapper">
      <div class="attributes">
        <!-- Physical -->
        <h3>PHYSICAL</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="statsBox container">
              <div>
                <label for="strengthSpecialisation">Strength:</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="strengthSpecialisation" id="strengthSpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="statsBox">
              <div>
                <label for="dexteritySpecialisation">Dexterity:</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="dexteritySpecialisation" id="dexteritySpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="statsBox">
              <div class="attributeName" id="attributeName">
                <label for="staminaSpecialisation">Stamina:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="attributeValue" id="attributeValue">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="staminaSpecialisation" id="staminaSpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you that's the first hurdle over - I think I can fly solo again for a little bit, will try and come back here to post the 'final' version of this (which will check multiple values against an array of options for a setup)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there - you need to replace `document.querySelectorAll` by `document.querySelector` (or by `document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0]`.

The reason for this is that `document.querySelectorAll` returns an array-like `HTMLCollection`, even if it finds only a single element.

```js
(function() {
  function testAttributes() {
    document.getElementById('testAttributesOutput').innerHTML = 'check' + physicalattribute;
    //get the value of the selected radio in group strength
    var str = document.querySelector('input[name^="strength"]:checked').value;
    //get the value of the selected radio in group dexterity
    var dex = document.querySelector('input[name^="dexterity"]:checked').value;
    //get the value of the selected radio in group stamina
    var sta = document.querySelector('input[name^="stamina"]:checked').value;
    //add the 3 values together
    var physicalattribute = str + dex + sta;
    //return value as a number not a string
    console.log(physicalattribute);
    //it prints a string where it expects a number - console prints NaN
  }
  // Validate attributes setup should display a a number between 0 and 12
  document.getElementById('testAttributes').onclick = testAttributes;
})();
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li input {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

li select {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

select {
  display: inline-block;
}

.attributes-wrapper,
.abilities-wrapper,
.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.advantages-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.statsBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.attributeName {
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.attributeValue {
  align-content: right;
}

.attributes,
.abilities,
.description ul {
  width: 31%;
  margin: 0;
}

.advantages {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inline select {
  width: 147%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button id="testAttributes">Test Attributes</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      Are Attributes valid?:
      <span id="testAttributesOutput"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>ATTRIBUTES</h2>
    <div class="attributes-wrapper">
      <div class="attributes">
        <!-- Physical -->
        <h3>PHYSICAL</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="statsBox container">
              <div>
                <label for="strengthSpecialisation">Strength:</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical strength" name="strength" id="strength_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="strengthSpecialisation" id="strengthSpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="statsBox">
              <div>
                <label for="dexteritySpecialisation">Dexterity:</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical dexterity" name="dexterity" id="dexterity_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="dexteritySpecialisation" id="dexteritySpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="statsBox">
              <div class="attributeName" id="attributeName">
                <label for="staminaSpecialisation">Stamina:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="attributeValue" id="attributeValue">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_1" value="0" checked>
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_2" value="1">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_3" value="2">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_4" value="3">
                <input type="radio" class="physical stamina" name="stamina" id="stamina_5" value="4">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="staminaSpecialisation" id="staminaSpecialisation" placeholder="Specialization if applicable">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close - this should do the trick:
https://jsfiddle.net/rkrzaynf/

basically, you just need to find the "checked" value and add them to each other.  `parseInt()` will convert from string to Integer so the math works.

Also, you have a nodeList array, which is a little different from a regular array.  Used this to loop: https://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/

```
var testAttributes = function() {
  var counter = 0;
  var attributes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
  //return value as a number not a string
  forEach(attributes, function(index, element) {
    counter += parseInt(element.value);
  });
  //it prints a string where it expects a number - console prints NaN
  document.querySelector('#testAttributesOutput').innerHTML = counter;
}

// forEach method, could be shipped as part of an Object Literal/Module
var forEach = function(array, callback, scope) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); // passes back stuff we need
  }
};

// Validate attributes setup should display a a number between 0 and 12
document.getElementById('testAttributes').addEventListener("click", testAttributes);
```